# Is it possible to specify the order of levels in Pandas factorize method?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am using pandas to factorize an array consisting of two types of strings. I want to make sure that one of the strings "XYZ" is always coded as a 0 and the other string "ABC" is always coded as 1.

Is it possible to do this? I looked up the documentation and didn't find anything useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of a `Categorical`, namely to (optionally) specify the actual categories when factorizing (as well as to specify an ordering if needed). The ordering of the categories will determine the factorization ordering. If its unspecified, then the order of appearance will be the order of the categories.

This requires 0.16.0 for the ability to specify the categories directly in an `.astype`; `Categoricals` were introduced in 0.15.0

```
In [10]: s = Series(list('aaabbaa')).astype('category',categories=list('ab'))

In [11]: s.cat.codes
Out[11]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    0
dtype: int8
```

Since we are now 'b','a' for the categories, then the codes are the opposite of above.

```
In [12]: s = Series(list('aaabbaa')).astype('category',categories=list('ba'))

In [13]: s.cat.codes
Out[13]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
dtype: int8
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT you can't do that directly with factorize, but it's quite easy to build a `dict` (which you can then use for pandas's [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)).

Suppose you have a Dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['m', 'n', 'a', 'e', 'f']})
```

and you'd like to create an ordering that has 'a' -> 0, 'e' -> 1. Then you can do this with

```
>> dict([('a', 0), ('e', 1)] + [(e, i + 1) \
..  for (i, e) in enumerate(set(df.a.values) - set({'a', 'e'}))])
{'a': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 3, 'm': 2, 'n': 1}
```

Again, you can just use this for pandas's `map`.